# astype(int) converts 4 to 3

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe column like below

```
df2['over_ball']

0     6.0
1     5.0
2     4.0
3     4.0
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     1.0
7     6.0
8     5.0
9     4.0
10    3.0
11    3.0
12    2.0
13    1.0
```

So I thought of removing the digits after decimal and used `astype(int)`. But I see that `astype(int)` converts the values of 4.0 to 3 and 2.0 to 1.

```
df2['over_ball'].astype(int)


0     6
1     5
2     3
3     3
4     3
5     1
6     1
7     6
8     5
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    1
13    1
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the output of `df2['over_ball'].dtype` before `astype` please?

Comment: The datatype is dtype('float64')

Comment: Can you try my workaround, please?

Comment: Faced the same problem even after the workaround. Then I tried to print them as str and noticed something else

df2['over_ball'].astype(str)


0       6.000000000000014

1                     5.0

2       3.999999999999986

3       3.999999999999986

4       3.000000000000007


Maybe this is the reason for that weird behavior. I will check further up on how these values are created and try to fix there. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Though they appear as 4.0 in dataframe, when we print them as string, I see the values as '3.999999'. Same behavior repeats for all the values which have conversion issue. So I think no issue with astype(int)...but the problem is with how the values are stored in my dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, your error is reproducible.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'over_ball': [3.99999999999, 1.99999999999]})
print(df2)

# Output:
   over_ball
0        4.0  # instead of 3.99999999999
1        2.0  # instead of 1.99999999999
```

A simple cast doesn't work as expected:

```
>>> df2['over_ball'].astype(int)
0    3
1    1
Name: over_ball, dtype: int64
```

You need to use `round` before `astype(int)`:

```
>>> df2['over_ball'].round().astype(int)
0    4
1    2
Name: over_ball, dtype: int64
```

**Tip**:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = "{:,.20f}".format
print(df2)

# Output:
               over_ball
0 3.99999999998999999917
1 1.99999999998999999917
```